# C recursion even odd index digits change

Tags: c, recursion

I have to input a number n(not array), lets say 691234 it has to be 'even' number of digits in it, and the output should look like this : 962143 -> it shifts the odd index with even index of the given number.If i have 0612 the output will be 612.I have a code, but its not even close to what i need to do,I tried dividing by 100 and returning a number but seems like nothing works for me.

Comment: Please try explaining again.  Q: What do you mean by "shift"?  Move a 10s place value? One value, or the entire string of digits?   Right, or left?  Q: What do you mean by "index"?  A 10s place position?  Starting from 0 or one?  from the most significant digit or the least significant digit?  Q: Why are you trying to do this?  A homework assignment?  Can you post the assignment verbatim? Q: What have you tried?  Can you post any code?

Comment: all i can say is that you need to shift the even index of the input number with the odd index of the input number, and no it is not homework. and I've been trying for hours to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int n){
    if(n > 99){
        int r = n % 100;
        int ret = f(n / 100);
        if(ret > 0)
            return ret * 100 + r % 10 * 10 + r / 10;
        else
            return ret;
    } else if(n > 9){
        return n % 10 * 10 + n / 10;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
int change(int n){
    int ret = f(n);
    return ret > 0 ? ret : n;
}
int main(void){
    int n;
    printf("input number : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", change(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you BULEPIXY it works fine, this is one heavy recursion for me. i wish i could do that easily as you.

Comment: I have seen your profile, seems like you answer every question, can you please share your experience with us? how are you that good sir?